# python flask : How to add a clickable column to the table and record it in the database after the operation

Tags: python, flask

```
<h3>Out of severice vehicles</h3>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for col in caidian_oos.columns %}
            <th>
                {{col}}
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        {% for row in caidian_oos.values %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
            <td>
                {{cell}}    
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

--

### The data object is a pandas dataframe

I want to add a column that user can click.
On user's click it should save the corresponding row to mysql database.

Comment: On my opinion, you should ask your search engine a lot, not stackoverflow about it. "Flask MySQL CRUD tutorial" should help. Just in case, CRUD means operations "create, read, update, delete". I'd suggest you to complete some tutorials where cases like yours are described in details.